# Use complete to create floating window of dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset containing dates when birds began migrating.  I'd like to add 7 rows to this dataset for each individuals containing the dates for the 7 days prior to their departure, with a fill column containing another variable (0,1) for whether the individual migrated on that date.

I've been trying to use the dplyr complete function, but I can't find a way to set this up so that the min and max values "float" depending on the migration date.

```
#migration dates for 10 individuals
date <- c(212, 224, 197, 210, 197, 224, 188, 212, 221, 198)
id <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(cbind(id, date))

#attempt to use complete function
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(depYN = 1) %>% 
  complete(date = date - seq(from = 7, to = 0),
           nesting(id),
           fill = list(depYN = 0))
```

I get the following warning message with this code:

```
Warning message:
In date - seq(from = 7, to = 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Also, it doesn't produce the results I'm looking for, instead depYN seems to randomly assign 1's and 0's and the dates ranges are wrong.

(updated) **Expected output for first two individuals:**

```
date   id   depYN
205    1    0
206    1    0
207    1    0
208    1    0
209    1    0
210    1    0
211    1    0
212    1    1
217    2    0
218    2    0
219    2    0
220    2    0
221    2    0
222    2    0
223    2    0
224    2    1
etc...
```

(updated) **Current code and actual dataset**

```
df1 <- lastDet %>% 
  mutate(doy = yday(depDate),
         depYN = 0) %>%
  select(-depDate)

df3 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(mfgID) %>% 
  expand(doy = ((doy-7):doy)) %>% 
  left_join(., {df1 %>% mutate(depYN = 1)}, 
            by = c('mfgID', 'doy')) %>% 
  arrange(mfgID, doy)

dput(lastDet[1:10,])
structure(list(speciesEN = c("Bank", "Bank", "Bank", "Bank", "Bank",       
  "Bank", "Bank", "Bank", "Bank", "Bank"), tagDeploySite = 
  structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L), .Label =       
  c("AU", "CB", "DE", "GA", "TR", "WE"), class = "factor"), sex = 
  structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
  "M"), class = "factor"), mfgID = c("46", "47", "48", "49", "40",             
  "41", "42", "44", "38", "50"), depDate = 
  structure(c(1533032604.2326, 1534086023.11, 1531737149.7107, 
  1532882823.5637, 1531737145.3837, 1534093849.7991, 1530997725.9412, 
  1533041446.3001, 1533820579.7317, 1531824345.5634), class = 
  c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -10L),       
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = 
  c("speciesEN",  "tagDeploySite", "sex"), drop = TRUE, indices = 
  list(0:3, 4:7, 8:9), group_sizes = c(4L, 4L, 2L), biggest_group_size 
  = 4L, labels = structure(list(speciesEN = c("Bank", "Bank", "Bank"), 
  tagDeploySite = structure(c(2L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("AU", "CB", 
  "DE", "GA", "TR", "WE"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 
  2L, 1L), .Label = c("F",     "M"), class = "factor")), row.names = 
  c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("speciesEN", 
  "tagDeploySite", "sex"), drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you need. Can you share your expected output?

Comment: @M-M added above.

Comment: @matt in the expected output `etc.` meant that the dataset continues. Your edit was harming the post. While there are many examples of `etc.` and `...` at the bottom of datasets shared here that are unnecessary, this wasn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `complete` as you do in your question

```
df %>%
    mutate(depYN = 1) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
        complete(date = ((date-7):date), 
                 nesting(id),
                 fill = list(depYN = 0))
```

```
# A tibble: 80 x 3
# Groups:   id [10]
      id  date depYN
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1   205     0
 2     1   206     0
 3     1   207     0
 4     1   208     0
 5     1   209     0
 6     1   210     0
 7     1   211     0
 8     1   212     1
 9     2   217     0
10     2   218     0
# ... with 70 more rows
```

Comment: I would still leave `nesting(id)` in `complete` (personal opinion). Cheers. +1

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I tried this with nesting(id) included, and while it works on the test dataset, it seems to drop over half of the dates in my actual dataset.  For the individuals where it's dropping the date, the correct range of dates is not being calculated.

Answer (score 1):

We can `expand` on `(date-7):date)` and the `join` with the original dataset to get the `depYN`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  expand(date=((date-7):date)) %>% 
  left_join(., {df %>% mutate(depYN = 1)}, by = c('id','date'))
#> # A tibble: 80 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [10]
#>       id  date depYN
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1   205    NA
#>  2     1   206    NA
#>  3     1   207    NA
#>  4     1   208    NA
#>  5     1   209    NA
#>  6     1   210    NA
#>  7     1   211    NA
#>  8     1   212     1
#>  9     2   217    NA
#> 10     2   218    NA
#> # ... with 70 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks @M-M.  This solution seems to be working mostly, although it looks like the mutate(depYN = 1) sets all these values to 1, rather than a mix of 1's and 0's.

Comment: @tnt you get a different output than what I have shown here? Can you share your df using dput so I can reproduce your error?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  The output with the test dataset is the same (although all the NA's should be 0's), but with my actual data, all the depYN's are 1's.

Comment: @tnt I understand, can you share a sample of your actual dataset which is reproducible with is? (Replacing NA with 0 should not be a hassle)

Comment: I updated my question above with a sample of the actual data and how I've incorporated your suggestion into my code.

Comment: @tnt I am still getting `NA` with your updated. dataset.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4JZ.png Update your R, and re-install your packages.